# bash add path to handle some files

Tags: bash

inside ~/mp3 I've some mp3 files.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
br=80
for a in $1*.{wav,mp3} ; 
do ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab $br "$br""_tmp/${a%.*} ["$br"].mp3" ;
```

with $1 add the path:

```
myscript.sh /home/$USER/mp3/
```

but I've the error:

```
/home/$USER/mp3/*.mp3: No such file or directory
```

so, the script does not run. Runs only when I execute the script inside ~mp3 dir.

Answer (score 3):

Put at the top script :

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

that way, if there's no mp3 like in your case (I guess), there will be no error.

When there's no mp3 file matching the wildcard, the shell take `*.mp3` literally.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because there are no `.mp3` files in the directory.
If you executed this look in a directory without `.mp3` and `.wav` files,
you would get 2 errors, one for `*.mp3` and a second for `*.wav` files.

A simple solution to make this work even when `.mp3` or `.wav` are missing,
is to add a test if the file exists:

```
for a in $1*.{wav,mp3}; do
    test -f "$a" || continue
    ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab $br "$br""_tmp/${a%.*} ["$br"].mp3"
done
```

That said, [@sputnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12574/sputnick)'s solution with `shopt -s nullglob` is better than this.

You should also quote `$1`, and you can simplify the quotes in the `ffmpeg` line:

```
for a in "$1"*.{wav,mp3}; do
    test -f "$a" || continue
    ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab $br "${br}_tmp/${a%.*} [$br].mp3"
done
```

Comment: janos thanks for your reply. My problem is execution of script: does not run. There're many files in "mp3" dir.

Comment: /home/wms/tmp/./myscript.sh /home/wms/tmp/mp3/ and does not run :-(

Comment: Jason: {a%.*} keep whole path, so ouput path will be: 32k_tmp/home/wms/tmp/mp3/audio1 [32k].mp3: No such file or directory. So I've to remove it.